# Confusión con guardar datos usando procedimiento almacenado en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy trabajando en C# con SqlServer.

Tengo un programa el cual me captura cierta información en unas listas y después esta información tengo que cargarla en una base de datos utilizando un procedimiento almacenado.

para esto tomé de ejemplo esta página: [link](http://elpaladintecnologico.blogspot.com/2011/02/c-y-procedimientos-almacenados-de-sql.html)

El nombre del procedimiento es: **zf_Boleta_Crear**.

Y por medio de un correo me pasaron el procedimiento con todo el código que trae, esta es una parte en donde se crea el procedimiento y la inserción de datos (el resto del código lo omití pero si es necesario lo agrego):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zf_Boleta_Crear]
    @Idboleta       int output,
    @IdCliente  int,
    @IdMonedaCIF    int,
    @IdMonedaVenta  int,
    @IdTipoDoc int,
    @TipoIngreso    char(1),
    @Archivo    varchar(60),
    @sTipoDocumento char(2),
    @sNroBoleta int,
    @sLineas    char(3),
    @sFecha datetime,
    @sNroContrato   char(4),
    @sTipoMovimiento    char(2),
    @sAñoZ  char(4),
    @sNumeroZ   char(6),
    @sItemZ char(4),
    @sMoneda    char(4),
    @sValorCIF  decimal(18,2),
    @sMonedaVenta   char(4),
    @sValorVenta    decimal(18,2),
    @Cadena varchar(150),
    @Estado char(1),
    @CreadoPor  varchar(25)/*,  
    @Local      int*/



AS

SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @IdMes_AñoTrabajo int

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Traer ID Mes_Año de Trabajo
select @IdMes_AñoTrabajo=IdMes_AñoTrabajado from zf_BloqueosMes_Año where Mes=month(@sFecha) and Año=year(@sFecha) and Bloqueado=0 
if @IdMes_AñoTrabajo is null select @IdMes_AñoTrabajo=min(IdMes_AñoTrabajado) from zf_BloqueosMes_Año where Bloqueado=0
---if @dv is null set @dv=0

    INSERT
        dbo.zf_Boleta
        (
        IdCliente,
        IdMonedaCIF,
        IdMonedaVenta,
        IdTipoDoc,
        TipoIngreso,
        Archivo,
        sTipoDocumento,
        sNroBoleta,
        sLineas,
        sFecha,
        sNroContrato,
        sTipoMovimiento,
        sAñoZ,
        sNumeroZ,
        sItemZ,
        sMoneda,
        sValorCIF,
        sMonedaVenta,
        sValorVenta,
        Cadena,
        Estado,
        CreadoPor,
        IdMes_AñoTrabajado
        )
    VALUES
        (
        @IdCliente,
        @IdMonedaCIF,
        @IdMonedaVenta,
        @IdTipoDoc,
        @TipoIngreso,
        @Archivo,
        @sTipoDocumento,
        @sNroBoleta,
        @sLineas,
        @sFecha,
        @sNroContrato,
        @sTipoMovimiento,
        @sAñoZ,
        @sNumeroZ,
        @sItemZ,
        @sMoneda,
        @sValorCIF,
        @sMonedaVenta,
        @sValorVenta,
        @Cadena,
        @Estado,
        @CreadoPor,
        @IdMes_AñoTrabajo
    )

    IF @@ERROR != 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('R -2; Se a generado un error cuando se ejecutaba una transacción en la Base de Datos: ZonaFranca. El procedimiento que genero el error se llama : dbo.zf_Boleta_Crear; Registro ID : %s',10, 2, @IdCliente  ) WITH LOG
        RETURN -2
    END

    SET @Idboleta = @@IDENTITY

COMMIT TRANSACTION
RETURN 0
```

Entonces, por lo que he encontrado en internet y en base a cuales son mis variables tengo lo siguiente:

Por una parte tengo mis variables de donde voy a sacar los datos:

```
public static string IDCliente = "";

        public static string[] salida;
        public static string[] salidda;
        public static string[] nDocumento;
        public static string[] lDocumento;
        public static string[] fDocumento;
        public static string[] nContrato;
        public static string[] tDocEntrada;
        public static string[] aDocEntrada;
        public static string[] nEntrada;
        public static string[] iDocEntrada;
        public static string[] mCIF;
        public static string[] vCIF;
        public static string[] mVenta;
        public static string[] vVenta;
```

En otra parte las declaro y le asigno los valores

La parte que me interesa es esta:

```
if (mostrarDatos != 0 && HayErrores == 0)
{
    string cadenaconexion = @"Data Source=00.00.00.00\rentas;Initial Catalog=ZonaFranca;Integrated Security=False; user id=**;password=*******";
    SqlConnection LaConexion = null;
    SqlTransaction LaTransaccion = null;
    comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    try
    {
        LaConexion = new SqlConnection();
        LaConexion.ConnectionString = cadenaconexion;
        LaConexion.Open();
        LaTransaccion = LaConexion.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("zf_Boleta_Crear", LaConexion, LaTransaccion);
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        int i = 0;
        while (i <= ContArchivo - 1)
        {
            comando.Parameters.Add("@IdCliente", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@IdMonedaCIF", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@IdTipoDoc", SqlDbType.Int, 10);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@TipoIngreso", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Archivo", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sTipoDocumento", SqlDbType.Char, 2);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sNroBoleta", SqlDbType.Int, 20);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sLineas", SqlDbType.Int, 1);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sFecha", SqlDbType.Date, 4);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sNroContrato", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sTipoMovimiento", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sAñoZ", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sNumeroZ", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sItemZ", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sMoneda", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sValorCIF", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sMonedaVenta", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@sValorVenta", SqlDbType.Decimal, 20);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Cadena", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Estado", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@CreadoPor", SqlDbType.Char, 30);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@IdMes_AñoTrabajo", SqlDbType.Char, 2);

            comando.Parameters["@IdCliente"].Value = 5;
            comando.Parameters["@IdMonedaCIF"].Value = mCIF[i];
            comando.Parameters["@IdTipoDoc"].Value = salida[i];
            comando.Parameters["@TipoIngreso"].Value = "M";
            comando.Parameters["@Archivo"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@sTipoDocumento"].Value = salidda[i];
            comando.Parameters["@sNroBoleta"].Value = nDocumento[i];
            comando.Parameters["@sLineas"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@sFecha"].Value = fDocumento[i];
            comando.Parameters["@sNroContrato"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@sTipoMovimiento"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@sAñoZ"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@sNumeroZ"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@sItemZ"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@sMoneda"].Value = mCIF[i];
            comando.Parameters["@sValorCIF"].Value = vCIF[i];
            comando.Parameters["@sMonedaVenta"].Value = mVenta[i];
            comando.Parameters["@sValorVenta"].Value = vVenta[i];
            comando.Parameters["@Cadena"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@Estado"].Value = "P";
            comando.Parameters["@CreadoPor"].Value = "";
            comando.Parameters["@IdMes_AñoTrabajo"].Value = "2";

            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            i++;
        }
        LaConexion.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception o)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(o.ToString());
    }
    //comando.Parameters.Add();

    MessageBox.Show("Los datos se guardaron correctamente", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Falta mostrar los datos, puede tener algun error en un código", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto al principio me tiraba unos errores que he podido solucionar pero ahora me arroja uno que dice

> System.NUllReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de objeto en Rentas_v1......Form2.cs:linea 438

y esa línea hace referencia a este código:

```
comando.Parameters["@sTipoDocumento"].Value = salidda[i];
```

Estuve comparando el tipo de datos y creo que está bien, *sTipoDocumento* es *char* de tamaño 2 y mi salidda[i] también tiene un tamaño de 2 pero es string.

Si alguien me puede ayudar a ver el error se los agradezco.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Ya intentaste tomar algunos de los datos que quieres insertar y hacer la prueba directamente en SQL-Server ? veo que en el primer segmento de tu while tienes **("@sTipoDocumento", SqlDbType.Int, 10);** y dicha variable en tu sp es de tipo char, también veo que a tu sp le falta **INTO** o solo pegaste alguna porción del query?

Comment: eso como dices, pegué una parte del procedimiento pero voy a modificar la pregunta para poner todo el código

Comment: de donde viene el array salida[] ??
Posiblemente en la posicion salida[i] que se le asigna al campo no trae nada

Comment: es salidda? seguro?

Comment: @gbianchi si, voy a poner el código pero me acabo de dar cuenta que no estoy respetando el orden de como tienen que ser ingresados los datos al procedimiento almacenado, podrá ser eso?

Comment: Como nota, cuando uno tiene esta clase de procedimientos, se hacen respetando el orden, respetando los nombres y generando de a 1 en uno cada parametro tanto en el sp como en el codigo. Si no, despues (como ves) es mucho mas dificil descubrir donde esta el error.

Comment: si me di cuenta jajaja, voy a revisar bien mi código y ordenar las inserciones como tú dices. De ser necesario se puede poner en espera la pregunta? quiero descartar todas las opciones por mi parte y si no me resulta, ahí vuelvo a preguntar o reabrir esta. Gracias

Comment: Si dice que es "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto" siempre o casi siempre es porque te falta instanciar una clase independientemente de que el dato venga o no.

Comment: Puede eliminarla y recuperarla posteriormente de ser necesario...